# Why is just 1 smtp server redirecting wrong?

Tags: email, redirect, dns, smtp

I have 2 domains: vanbulck.com and oliviervanbulck.com. I use oliviervanbulck.com for my personal website, and vanbulck.com for my e-mail address. Vanbulck.com also redirects to oliviervanbulck.com, so they reach my website both.

Most of the time this works, but a friend of me told me that he was unable to reach me by mail, and it was just by one smtp-server. This server does the redirect to oliviervanbulck.com instead of using the mx record which redirect to outlook.com (domain service from Microsoft).

My DNS from vanbulck.com is set like this: http://puu.sh/6o6TX.png

What do I have to change for letting this work correctly? That also that smtp-server can send emails to me correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to receive mail on:mail.vanbulck.com or vanbulck.com. Your mx-record is for vanbulck.com

Comment: I want to receive email on vanbulck.com, which is redirecting to the servers from outlook.

Comment: It seems like your olivervanbulck redirect is causing the trouble. If you try this mx-tool i goes directly to your cname redirect: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3avanbulck.com&run=toolpage# 

Try remove the cname for a test, and see if that helps. Have you followed this guide http://www.wpsite.net/how-to-setup-outlook-com-for-your-domain/ for mail settings on outlook?

Comment: The website you gave me doesn't show me an error. I have tried to add the TXT-record in DNS from the guide, I hope this will help. The weird thing is that there's just 1 person who can't reach me, all the other mails are perfectly working.